# Modifying a Struct of OpenGL Matrices

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I have a struct that consists of 4 vectors that I am using to create a rectangle. One of the matrices defines the color of the rectangle. Each time I draw a rectangle, I need to update the color of it. Problem is, I don't know how to update this part of the struct. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
typedef struct {
    GLKVector3 positionCoordinates;
    GLKVector2 textureCoordinates;
    GLKVector3 normalCoordinates;
    GLKVector4 colorCoordinates;
} VertexData;

VertexData unitSquare[] = {
    { {-0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
    { {-0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} },
    { { 0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}, { 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f} }
};

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    ...
    // lame attempt to update the color of one vertex
    unitSquare->colorCoordinates[0] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three things wrong with your code

1. Unitsquare is an array of structs. Use this

   `unitSquare[0].colorCoordinate = GLKVector4Make(.1, .1, .1, .1);`
2. Even if you update the unitSquare variable on the CPU, you still need to update your Vertex Buffer Object with the new color by binding your buffer with glBindBuffer and using glBufferData, or the GPU won't . But don't do that yet because....
3. All your vertices have the same color in your sample -- if this is true throughout your program, its far more efficient to use a uniform instead -- look up the glUniform3fv function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. When I change my code to what you suggest, I get an error `Expected expression`. Any idea why this is?

Comment: Replacing "->" with "." works for me. Its because you aren't making an array of pointers -- "->" is equivalent to dereferencing a pointer to a struct then using the "." operator.

Comment: I realized the misuse of the -> operator too, but that's when I got the error. I can't figure out why I get this error, or even what the error means.

Comment: Wow.... I completely missed that it didn't compile a second time.... this most recent edit should do it.

Comment: I did that, too. Yes, it compiles, but my rectangles don't change their color. I'm sure that this is related to your second point. I tried to rebind them, but failed. Can I ask you to show me how you would do this, please? (I've been working on passing these as uniforms, but I can't get that to work either...) Thanks a million for all of your help.